# How to make a child div = parent's height which has display:inline-block and unspecified height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

I have to separate the background of a button from the parent, for reasons related to the tumblr customisation quirks.

Here is the html:

```
<a href="link">
    <div class="innerNest"> //I'm guessing we need this to bring the two divs to T:0 L:0
        <div class="buttonText">{tumblr variable}</div>
        <div class="buttonBG"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

This is the css I'm stuck with, *at least for the  tag*:

```
a{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I've made a very descriptive jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hVuaf/35/

NB: It's a no brainer to just go like this for eg (inline CSS for demo purposes):

```
<a href="link" style="background-color:#fff;display:inline-block">Link</a>
```

But i just can't, it's got to do with me wanting control over variable assigned colours in Tumblrs customised theme edit panels. Basically it supports colours to the hills, but i need to work with rgba, not #, hence my need to separate the components of the button.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you do `<a href="link" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5); display:inline-block">Link</a>`?

Comment: I can't because i need to separate the values of the background and the foreground due to an issue with tumblrs customisation of theme settings. Trust me, if i could i would. I know it looks like i'm doing a newbie here, but the fact is i need to separate the background from the text completely.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate the values"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

http://jsfiddle.net/cdj2L/

Basically, I've set the anchor to position:relative and then the text inside is just standard. Then the background I've set to absolute and width/height are 100%, filling the anchor. Finally, a z-index sorts out the layering.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Good solution if the two divs inside `<a>` are required.

Comment: Thanks so much, what do you do when you get two correct answers? Only gave the green tick to mrtsherman cos of the reduction of divs.

Comment: Ahh, no worries, I thought you needed to keep those div's for some theming reason in tumblr. If you can remove that one though, why not just have one div inside (or a span, I prefer using spans for some reason) and just style that up?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? I removed the bg element and just used the container to set the background.

```
<a href="link">
    <div class="inlineNest">
        <div class="btText">Link</div>
    </div>
</a>

.inlineNest {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

.btText {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/hVuaf/43/

Comment: Thank you! nice that the div is removed too. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this: http://jsfiddle.net/hVuaf/45/